# juju consolidation and constrains

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying out Ubuntu cloud infrastructure in a lab environment, I had couple attempts and fails mostly because my references are outdated. "My main ref. now is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure"

My lab consists of three powerful servers, 3 low PCs, and 4 notebooks.

Constrains:
Due to diversity in resources. I tried to selectively direct juju to deploy services by commissioning the low nodes first then bootstrap/deploy the needed service. But I saw in another ticket here that I can do that by specifying constrains.
Is there a reference/ticket/how to article for that?

Consolidation:
As jitsu is obsolete, and juju deploy to still consumes whole nodes for low services, I think add-node is the best alternative, yet again I lack the proper documentation to try this.

So I guess I'm asking for some demo case studies or best practices guides from the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-constraints.html) any of the following [constraints](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/reference-constraints.html) to pick the hardware required for particular machines or services. If you're using maas, you can set up [tags](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/tags.html) on your nodes and then specify them with the `tags` constraint in juju; otherwise the `cpu-cores`, `mem`, and `root-disk` constraints may be enough for the situation you've described.

Note that the relevant part of jitsu's functionality has been consumed by juju: if you used, say, `juju add-machine --constraints tags=bigserver` to create a new machine, and that machine got given id `3`, you could then use `--to 3` with `juju deploy` or `juju add-unit` to place service units on that particular instance.